# PlotRange label digit precision

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy, style

I'm trying to plot a set of points, Mathematica create the plot with the right range but it doesn't show all the digits (only shows up to six digits):

```
ListPlot[Table[{taillebase, 
   eigenvaluess[taillebase, λ][[1]]}, {taillebase, 31, 36}], 
 AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Taille Base], HoldForm[Energie]}, 
 PlotLabel -> None, LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}, 
 PlotRange -> {0.8037705, 0.8037715}]
```

[image]

What can I do to have the range I indicated in the function {0.8037705, 0.8037715} on the Y axe instead of this truncated version?

Edit:

The method given by @george2079 works fine up to seven digits precision, if I try to go higher than that I get this problem:

```
ListPlot[Table[{wp, 
   En /. FindRoot[solfonpai2f[wp][En][3], {En, 0}]}, {wp, 20, 24, 1}],
  AxesLabel -> {HoldForm["Working Precision"], HoldForm["Energy"]}, 
 PlotLabel -> None, LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}, 
 PlotRange -> {0.80377060, 0.80377070}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {#, NumberForm[N@#, {10, 9}]} & /@ 
    FindDivisions[{0.80377060, 0.80377070}, 10]}, 
 BaseStyle -> {PrintPrecision -> 10}]
```

[image]

Any idea how could I solve it?

Comment: Add `BaseStyle -> {PrintPrecision -> 7}` to your ListPlot options.

Comment: A good question should provide all expression for reproducing.

Comment: @CarlWoll I tried BaseStyle -> {PrintPrecision -> 7} but it doesn't seem to work, I keep getting the same result.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my suggestion only works in M11.

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 11, it works fine up to 7 digits, but if I do 8 or higher ie. BaseStyle -> {PrintPrecision -> 8} , it ignores it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amplifying on my comments. The following should just work:

```
plot = ListPlot[
    Table[{x, x}, {x,31,36}],
    AxesLabel->{HoldForm[Taille Base],HoldForm[Energie]},
    PlotLabel->None,LabelStyle->{GrayLevel[0]},
    BaseStyle->{PrintPrecision->11},
    PlotRange->{0.80377, 0.80377001}
]
```

[image]

For some reason [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot) can't believe that you really want such a small plot range, and so it changes the requested [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange) to something more "reasonable":

```
Options[plot, PlotRange]
```

> {PlotRange -> {{31., 36.}, {0, 1.60754}}}

The workaround is to use [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show):

```
Show[plot, AxesOrigin->{31, .80377}, PlotRange->{{31, 36}, {.80377, .80377001}}]
```

[image]

Note that is unnecessary to specify explicit [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks), the automatic behavior is just fine.

Comment: Lovely, thanks for taking the time to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListPlot[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.803771, 10^-6], 40], 
 PlotRange -> {0.8037705, 0.8037715}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {#, NumberForm[N@#, {10, 7}]} & /@ 
    FindDivisions[{0.8037705, .8037715}, 8]}]
```

[image]

Comment: The method given works fine up to seven digits precision, if I try to go higher than that I get this problem mentioned in the edit, any idea how to get around it? @george2079

Comment: It looks like `ListPlot` thinks that the vertical range is too small, and so it changes it to something "reasonable". Try using `Show[plot, PlotRange->{0.80377060, 0.80377070}, AxesOrigin->{0, .8037706}]`